# Sqldependency handle more than one table changes in onchange event

Tags: sql, vb.net, service-broker, sqldependency

I am using [sqldependency](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events) for notifying any changes in database by using `onchange` events. Can a single `onchange` event be used to handle more than one table changes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically it works like any change in the result of your sql dependency query will be notified back. 
For example if a query like below is registered for sql dependency,

```
SELECT Name, Designation FROM Employee
```

Then, you will be notified everytime the result of the above query is changed in the database, whether a row is inserted or deleted or any of the Name or Designation is changed.

Any query under the constraints mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx) can be registered for sql dependency.